# using a Qt dll in MFC

Tags: c++, qt, mfc

the Qt dll defines some interfaces, one of them need to use `QNetworkManageAccess` Object, while MFC process step into `QNetworkManageAccess.post()`, a dead loop occurs, and the service does not response.

But if Qt application call the Qt dll, everything is ok,
thx!!!

Comment: Did you turn on event loop? And you could use `waitForReadyRead()` to wait for data being posted.

Answer (score 0):

try to use WinMigration. I'm not sure but it could help.
http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/qtwinmigrate/winmigrate-walkthrough.html