# Link errors when using QtMinMigrate with Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, dll, mfc

After some tries, I am finally able to compile QtwinMigrate library (QtSolutions_MFCMigrationFramework-head.lib) on Qt5.3.

See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008558/using-a-qt-dll-in-mfc/24826165#24826165) to get the context:

But when I try to use this library with the QtwinMigrate sample code from an MFC application, I get the following link errors :

```
* error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class QApplication * __cdecl QMfcApp::instance()
* error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QWinWidget::QWinWidget()
* error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "__declspec(dllimport) public: static int __cdecl QMfcApp::run(class CWinApp *)
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Possibly missing the dlls in your path? Framework DLL should be in LIBS path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've checked my LIBs path and there isn't any DLL file which is missing...